# iPhone: How to programmatically convert String entered by user into Init caps?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, nsstring

I have a textbox where in user enters the string.

I want to programmatically convert this string to init caps.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using this [UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords or UITextAutocapitalizationTypeAllCharacters](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords)

UPDATE

[capitalizedString](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-uppercaseString) or [upperCaseString](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-uppercaseString) will help you

`[textField.text uppercaseString];` will give you all the characters in textfield as capital letters

Comment: I don't want to restrict the user to entering text in textField and I want to change it after I fetch the value from my textField into my NSString variable. How can I do that?

Comment: +1 for Quick Answer and pointing out `capitalizedString` but by then I got @Meghan's answer which was simple to understand and worked. :)

Comment: @PARTH: No offense but I answered before @Meghan. Just want to inform you thats all so that you look for it next time.

Comment: capitalizedString returns A string with the first character from each word in the receiver changed to its corresponding uppercase value, and all remaining characters set to their corresponding lowercase values.

Comment: I thought uppercaseString is what you needed

Comment: @7KV7: Oh I am sorry really didnt know that was the case. I have accepted your answer as an answer.

Comment: Oh that was ok I just wanted you to be careful next time.

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
  myString = [myTextField.text capitalizedString];
```

Comment: Sorry man I just wanted to point out his mistake. Nothing personal. Sorry again.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `UITextInputTraits` protocol which is confirm by both (`UITextView` and `UITextField`)
input method ...

```
@property(nonatomic) UITextAutocapitalizationType autocapitalizationType
```

Try with `UITextAutocapitalizationTypeAllCharacters` to Capitalize all characters automatically.

```
myTextView.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeAllCharacters;
```

Eidted:
If you want to Capitalize after getting the text from you textView use below

```
  NSString myTextString = [myTextView.text capitalizedString];
```